# rule security firebase denied after create new user current user still logged in

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

please help me!
On my web Fluter I have an user that set role to admin (using custom claims).when admin logged in could access read, write data until admin create a new user using email, password Firebase auth admin could not access data. An exception raised `[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] Missing or insufficient permissions.`

rule security:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
        }

        function getRole() {
            return request.auth.token.role;
        }

        function isOneOfRoles(array) {
            return isSignedIn() && (getRole() in array);
        }

        function isValidNewDoiTuong() {
            return isOneOfRoles(['admin','tp_kd','nv_kd']);
        }

        // tinh trang khach hang
        match /tinhtrang_kh/{tinhtrang} {


            function isValidNewTinhTrangKH() {
                return isOneOfRoles(['admin','tp_kd']);
            }

            function onlyContentChanged() {
                // Ensure that title and roles are unchanged and that no new
                // fields are added to the document.
                return request.resource.data.dtID == resource.data.dtID
                && request.resource.data.roles == resource.data.roles
                && request.resource.data.keys() == resource.data.keys();
            }

            // Split writing into creation, deletion, and updating. Only an
            // owner can create or delete a story but a writer can update
            // story content.
            allow create: if isValidNewTinhTrangKH();
            allow delete: if isOneOfRoles(['admin','tp_kd']);
            allow update: if isOneOfRoles( ['admin','tp_kd'])
            || (isOneOfRoles( ['tp_kd']) && onlyContentChanged());
            allow read: if isSignedIn();
        }


        /* end tinh trang khach hang */
        // users
        match /tk_users/{tkuser} {     
            // Split writing into creation, deletion, and updating. Only an
            // owner can create or delete a story but a writer can update
            // story content.
            allow create: if isOneOfRoles(['admin']);
            allow delete: if isOneOfRoles(['admin']);
            allow update: if isOneOfRoles( ['admin']);
            allow read:   if isSignedIn();
        }

        /* end users */      
    }
}
```

code set custom claim:

```
//users
exports.updateAccess = functions.firestore
.document('tk_users/{userId}')
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const customClaims = {
        role: newValue.role
    };

    // Set custom user claims on this update.
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(
    context.params.userId, customClaims)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Done!")
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

code authenticate:

```
Future<AppUser?> signIn(
    {required String email,
    required String password,
    bool createAccount = false}) async {
        UserCredential userCreds;
        if (createAccount) {
            userCreds = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        } else {
            userCreds = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        }
        User? user = userCreds.user;
        String? role = '';
        
        if (!createAccount) {
            final idTokenResult = await user!.getIdTokenResult();
            role = idTokenResult.claims?['role'];
        }   

    return user == null
    ? null
    : AppUser(email: user.email ?? "", documentId: user.uid, role: role);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but `newValue = change.after.data()` should return the document data only. And this data does not contain a role: `newValue.role`.

Also, I would try removing the `async`.

This might work:

```js
exports.updateAccess = functions.firestore
.document('tk_users/{userId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {          // NO ASYNC <<<<<<<<<<<<
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const customClaims = {
        role: "admin"                     // ADMIN <<<<<<<<<<<<
    };

    // Set custom user claims on this update.
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(
    context.params.userId, customClaims)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Done!")
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: I agree remove async but set admin to all user not expectation .I want to admin user can create new user from firebase auth after it also add the user to tk_users collection Firestore that its document has role fileld .when admin update role filed after set custom claims for the user

Comment: `admin` is not set to all users, but it authorizes calls made by `admin.auth()` with the role of `admin`.

Comment: but that statement only trigger when update action not create?